# Using extra kwargs for Aggregate in Django

Tags: python, django, orm, aggregate-functions, django-orm

If you look at the definition of Aggregate functions in Django, you'll see that they are actually classes subclassed from `django.db.models.aggregates.Aggregate` which have a constructor that looks like this:

```
class Aggregate(object):
"""
Default Aggregate definition.
"""
def __init__(self, lookup, **extra):
    """Instantiate a new aggregate.

     * lookup is the field on which the aggregate operates.
     * extra is a dictionary of additional data to provide for the
       aggregate definition

    Also utilizes the class variables:
     * name, the identifier for this aggregate function.
    """
    self.lookup = lookup
    self.extra = extra

    #... the rest is truncated
```

What this extra keyword arguments are used for? Can I use them to make more complex queries with aggregates? I tried to find any docs on it, but didn't succeed. I believe it's not documented, but anyway, what are these extra arguments and what can be done with them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sure,

Just look at the source, [`extra` is unpacked and passed to the "backend-specific" aggregate class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6b2/django/db/models/aggregates.py#L58).

The backend specific aggregates for the `SQL` backend are found in `db.models.sql.aggregates`.

There, you'll see that [`Sum`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6b2/django/db/models/sql/aggregates.py#L101) accepts a `distinct` parameter, and [`StdDev`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6b2/django/db/models/sql/aggregates.py#L113) and [`Variance`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6b2/django/db/models/sql/aggregates.py#L123) accept a `sample` parameter.